# Enabling 'websocket' module on Prosody (Windows)

Tags: windows, lua, websocket, xmpp

In order to enable 'websocket' module (https://code.google.com/p/prosody-modules/wiki/mod_websocket) on Prosody, the Lua used by Prosody must have a bit library installed, such as LuaBitOp. The thing is: Prosody for Windows uses a bundled Lua, under 'PROSODY_HOME/bin', which doesn't have a bit library.

I tried placing the 'bit.dll' file under 'PROSODY_HOME/bin', which is where the libraries used by the bundled Lua are, but, upon running Prosody, when it tries to load the 'websocket' module, it gives an error saying that Lua doesn't have a bit library installed.

I found it strange; even though I tested by running the bundled Lua console and inputing:

> require"bit"

It didn't give me any error and I was able to use it without any problems. On a side note: I can't use another XMPP server, I have to use Prosody.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Find the file `mod_websocket.lua` in your Prosody installation and put a `require"bit"` before the `pcall(function() bit = require"bit"; end);` line. The resulting error message in the console should tell you exactly where Lua is looking for the bit module. Don't forget to undo your modifications afterwards ...

Comment: @siffiejoe I did what you suggested and turns out that it was looking for it under 'PROSODY_HOME/lib' and 'PROSODY_HOME/src'; I've put 'bit.dll' under 'PROSODY_HOME/lib' and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uppon doing what @siffiejoe suggested, I discovered that it was looking for it under 'PROSODY_HOME/lib' and 'PROSODY_HOME/src'; I've put 'bit.dll' under 'PROSODY_HOME/lib' and it worked.